# Calendar issue on OS X Mavericks

Tags: upgrade, calendar, macos

When I try to open Calendar I'm told "You can't use this version of the application 'Calendar' with this version of OS X. You have Calendar 6.0."

Any ideas why this could be happening? I just uprgaded to OS X 10.9 Mavericks from OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion today.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the upgrade has failed to update your Calendar app. OS X 10.9 has Calendar v7.0 and if you do have 6.0 then something went wrong.

I would suspect that there is some serious problem with your existing Calendar app such as permissions.

Delete your Calendar app and either grab a copy from another Mavericks Mac or re-install 10.9.

If you go the re-install route I would be tempted to do a reformat and clean install myself, just to make sure there are no hidden gotchas since you already have one. At the least I would boot into recovery mode and run "Fix Permissions" before the re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you inadvertently made a copy of the calendar application. Make sure that the application you are trying to launch is contained in your Applications folder.

One way to do this is using spotlight (CMD-Space), type "calendar", then click the result which has "Applications" in the context menu to the left.

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I find I usually have better luck with doing complete formats and installs of new operating systems. As others have pointed out, sometimes steps in the update don't write over existing files they should because the permissions got messed up somewhere along the way.

First, please make sure your user data is backed up (a couple of times) and validate that you can read it from the other source.

Then reinstall using OS X Installer.  You'll need to use the Disk Utility to format the drive clean.